# SUM - why i get different sum when i use sum and use calculator)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Good afternoon.

Noticed the strangeness in calculating the amount in the field.

Vaues table:

[image: Vaues table]

Type field - float.

I make select sum:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as cost FROM Table
```

In result i get `sum` = 20.47497010231018;

[image: sum result]

I use calculator) and i get `sum` = 20,47497

Tell me please why do I get different results?

Comment: yeah, basically that's a floating point common issue. do not use float as a type in mysql, you have other data types that will do the trick.

Comment: @Sebas tell me more please, what types of fields can replace the float?

Comment: Time to read "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic" http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Those two numbers are almost identical (assuming that your calculator is using European format and your MySql is in American format).  Why do you call them "very different"?  Or is it just the formatting issue?

Comment: @Loki, it depends what is the business meaning of what you're storing in that column. (money...)

Comment: @RBarryYoung i dont said **very** different. i sai ifferent because the results are not the same and I need to round the value received in the request...

Comment: @LeoLoki Your title does say "**very** different".   But that's OK, I was making sure that that was what you meant.

Comment: @Sebas yes, this column stores the value of money.

Comment: @RBarryYoung sorry - i see now that title have **very**. i clear this) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, read this: http://floating-point-gui.de/

So, the problem is that floating point numbers - the internal implementation for decimal numbers in hardware, and used by most languages and applications, does not map 1 to 1 to numbers in base 10, as we are used. The underlying values are expressed in base 2, and have a limited precision. Some numbers that can be represented with few digits in the decimal notation can actually need much more digits in the native format - leading to rounding errors.

The article linked above explains it in detail.

Comment: Thanks for my new knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of differences are not enough to be worried about in most situations.

Floating point numbers are notorious for being slightly off of the intended values because of the number of bits and how floating point numbers are stored in binary. For example, as demonstrated [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), a decimal value of `0.1` has an actual `double` value of `0.10000000149011612`. Close, but not exact.

A technique I've seen used in some applications that need absolutely accurate latitude and longitude numbers is that they'll keep the values in integral data types that are equivalent to the float multiplied by some power of 10. For example, a [GeoPoint in the Google Maps API v1 on Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint) measures in micro degrees. Instead of a latitude and longitude like `54.123428, 60.809234` to preserve the values precisely they'd be ints: `54123428, 60809234`. To depict this, they'd call the variables `latitudeE6` and `longitudeE6` to indicate that it's the real latitude or longitude multiplied by 1E6 (the scientific notation of 10^6).

Comment: Thanks too for my new knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

Use `DECIMAL(16, 4)` (for example) type for your currency columns, where `4` is the number of digits after the `.`

You will have to trim the trailing zeros though, since for instance `10` would appear `10.0000`. This is however easily done.

Comment: yes, i use Decimal(10,4) already. Thanks.